# After advertising, sound disappears in the game

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, audio, ads

I'm trying to create a complete unit game.

I have the following problem: after adMob advertisement with sound (this is important), the sound completely disappears in the game. Scene reloading, MobileAds.SetApplicationMuted (false) and audioSource.mute = false don't help. This problem is absent on all androids that I tested (about 6 different models) and on iPhone 6 in iPhone 6c, the problem occurs only on iPhone 11 (I tested two phones).

I have tried many solutions for nothing. The most up-to-date information at the moment is the logs from iPhine 11 from xCode.

the most interesting errors are:

1. veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2. veganrunner[4766:1537699] [avas] AVAudioSession.mm:997:-[AVAudioSession setActive:withOptions:error:]: Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session.

logs from iPhone 11 (full version):

```
2020-10-15 17:31:46.369580+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] UnityIAP UnityEarlyTransactionObserver: Created
2020-10-15 17:31:46.369836+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] UnityIAP UnityEarlyTransactionObserver: Registered for lifecycle events
CrashReporter: initialized
2020-10-15 17:31:46.518872+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] Built from '2019.4/staging' branch, Version '2019.4.12f1 (225e826a680e)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp'
-> applicationDidFinishLaunching()
2020-10-15 17:31:46.869608+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] UnityIAP UnityEarlyTransactionObserver: Added to the payment queue
-> applicationDidBecomeActive()
[Subsystems] Discovering subsystems at path /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2265ED33-8636-4536-870A-F3089C7C089B/veganrunner.app/Data/UnitySubsystems
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Renderer: Apple A13 GPU
Vendor:   Apple Inc.
Version:  OpenGL ES 3.0 Metal - 66.6
GLES:     3
 GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_pvrtc_sRGB GL_EXT_read_format_bgra GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod GL_EXT_shadow_samplers GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_APPLE_clip_distance GL_APPLE_color_buffer_packed_float GL_APPLE_copy_texture_levels GL_APPLE_rgb_422 GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_IMG_read_format GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc
OPENGL LOG: Creating OpenGL ES 3.0 graphics device ; Context level  <OpenGL ES 3.0> ; Context handle -2141302080
OPENGL LOG: OpenGLES3 is deprecated on this platform
Initialize engine version: 2019.4.12f1 (225e826a680e)
2020-10-15 17:31:47.432886+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537461]  - <Google>[I-ACS025031] AdMob App ID changed. Original, new: (nil), ca-app-pub-8737631907101937~4117797731
2020-10-15 17:31:47.538109+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537461]  - <Google>[I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60802000 started
2020-10-15 17:31:47.541555+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537461]  - <Google>[I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -APMAnalyticsDebugEnabled
2020-10-15 17:31:47.552037+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UnityViewControllerStoryboard: 0x1032731d0>.
2020-10-15 17:31:47.555891+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537462]  - <Google>[I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-10-15 17:31:47.637293+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537455]  - <Google>[I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-10-15 17:31:47.682450+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537563]  - <Google>[I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
ERROR: Shader Hidden/PostProcessing/MultiScaleVO shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/PostProcessing/Debug/Waveform shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/PostProcessing/Debug/Vectorscope shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/PostProcessing/Debug/LightMeter shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/PostProcessing/Debug/Histogram shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/PostProcessing/ScreenSpaceReflections shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
UnloadTime: 7.325583 ms
Level loaded 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Game loaded
GameManager:Awake()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Game initialized 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

2020-10-15 17:31:52.526944+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [YandexMobileMetrica] Set track location enabled 0
2020-10-15 17:31:52.532824+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [YandexMobileMetrica] Activated. Version:3.11.1, Release build 18489
2020-10-15 17:31:52.532903+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [YandexMobileMetrica] A debugger is attached. Most crashes will not be reported.
Save file not found in /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8C6A0568-5AD1-4384-A1F9-7CB7B76236E6/Documents/iap.save
SaveManager:LoadIAPProfiler()
IAPManager:LoadData()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

IAP loaded 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Market loaded
MarketManager:Awake()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Market initialized 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

0 + -28 + 60 + 150 + 22.5 = 204.5 - finishZPos
LevelSpawner:SpawnLevel()
LevelSpawner:Start()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

UnityIAP Version: 2.0.0
UnityEngine.Purchasing.StandardPurchasingModule:Instance(AppStore)
IAPManager:InitializePurchasing()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

2020-10-15 17:31:52.624892+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] UnityIAP: Requesting 1 products
2020-10-15 17:31:52.777347+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] UnityIAP: Requesting product data...
2020-10-15 17:31:54.124755+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537455] UnityIAP: Received 1 products
2020-10-15 17:31:54.125848+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537455] UnityIAP: No App Receipt found
2020-10-15 17:31:54.135690+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] UnityIAP: No App Receipt found
OnInitialized: PASS
IAPManager:OnInitialized(IStoreController, IExtensionProvider)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:CheckForInitialization()
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:OnProductsRetrieved(List`1)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.AppleStoreImpl:OnProductsRetrieved(String)
System.Action:Invoke()
UnityEngine.Purchasing.Extension.UnityUtil:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

UnityIAP: Initialization complete with  1 items
UnityEngine.Purchasing.Promo:ProvideProductsToAds(HashSet`1, Boolean)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.AppleStoreImpl:OnProductsRetrieved(String)
System.Action:Invoke()
UnityEngine.Purchasing.Extension.UnityUtil:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

2020-10-15 17:31:54.136238+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] UnityIAP: Add transaction observer
2020-10-15 17:31:54.136287+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] UnityIAP UnityEarlyTransactionObserver: Request to initiate queued payments
2020-10-15 17:32:01.288259+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537558] [YandexMobileMetrica] Client event is received: Игрок НЕ прошёл 4 уровень, он врезался в препятствие. (apiKey: 8eee54b7-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx96bf).
2020-10-15 17:32:01.303594+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537563] [YandexMobileMetrica] Client event is saved to db: Игрок НЕ прошёл 4 уровень, он врезался в препятствие. (apiKey: 8eee54b7-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx96bf).
Market saved
System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
Player:Crash(ObstacleChunkGroup)
Obstacle:Crashed(Player)
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

haptics stoped (usually because they have finished playing)
System.Action:Invoke()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

2020-10-15 17:32:04.052005+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537563] [YandexMobileMetrica] Client event is received: Игрок решил посмотреть (продолжить уровень) рекламу. (apiKey: 8eee54b7-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx96bf).
2020-10-15 17:32:04.056249+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] <Google> To get test ads on this device, set: GADMobileAds.sharedInstance.requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = @[ @"a9016ed766687d5de9e32dfa87b64850" ];
2020-10-15 17:32:04.063667+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537563] [YandexMobileMetrica] Client event is saved to db: Игрок решил посмотреть (продолжить уровень) рекламу. (apiKey: 8eee54b7-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx96bf).
2020-10-15 17:32:04.183464+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:04.183490+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:04.185149+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:04.188933+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:04.237736+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
--//--
2020-10-15 17:32:06.352934+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:06.368974+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:06.407489+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:06.419925+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:07.410927+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:07.420268+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
HandleRewardedAdLoaded event received
ADManager:HandleOnRewardVideoLoaded(Object, EventArgs)
System.EventHandler`1:Invoke(Object, TEventArgs)
System.EventHandler`1:Invoke(Object, TEventArgs)
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

2020-10-15 17:32:07.434270+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:07.434365+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:07.521384+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:07.585163+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:07.785422+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:07.985719+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:08.024800+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
--//--
2020-10-15 17:32:12.914277+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:12.928949+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:12.934322+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:12.985304+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:13.164361+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
HandleRewardedAdRewarded event received for 10 coins
ADManager:HandleUserEarnedReward(Object, Reward)
System.EventHandler`1:Invoke(Object, TEventArgs)
System.EventHandler`1:Invoke(Object, TEventArgs)
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

2020-10-15 17:32:13.173598+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:13.186839+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:13.200822+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:13.385369+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
--//--
2020-10-15 17:32:15.185953+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:15.221110+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:15.221421+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:15.295343+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:15.341505+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537699] [general] Connection to daemon was invalidated
2020-10-15 17:32:15.342036+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:15.343568+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:15.363766+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:15.367103+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:15.367682+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:15.371294+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:15.371858+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:15.373798+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:15.991501+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537699] [avas] AVAudioSession.mm:997:-[AVAudioSession setActive:withOptions:error:]: Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session.
2020-10-15 17:32:15.995125+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:15.996682+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:15.997522+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:15.997656+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
HandleRewardedAdClosed event received
ADManager:HandleOnRewardVideoClosed(Object, EventArgs)
System.EventHandler`1:Invoke(Object, TEventArgs)
System.EventHandler`1:Invoke(Object, TEventArgs)
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

2020-10-15 17:32:16.018349+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537558] [YandexMobileMetrica] Client event is received: Игрок посмотрел (продолжить уровень) рекламу. (apiKey: 8eee54b7-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx96bf).
2020-10-15 17:32:16.023358+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537558] [YandexMobileMetrica] Client event is saved to db: Игрок посмотрел (продолжить уровень) рекламу. (apiKey: 8eee54b7-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx96bf).
2020-10-15 17:32:16.027333+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:16.027388+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:16.027887+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:16.028163+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:16.028213+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:16.028234+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:16.028308+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:16.028332+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:16.145783+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [ProcessSuspension] 0x12a8e64f0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-10-15 17:32:16.145854+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [ProcessSuspension] 0x12a8e7c60 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-10-15 17:32:16.505373+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:19.269306+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537699] [YandexMobileMetrica] Client event is received: Игрок НЕ прошёл 4 уровень, он врезался в препятствие. (apiKey: 8eee54b7-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx96bf).
Market saved
System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
Player:Crash(ObstacleChunkGroup)
Obstacle:Crashed(Player)
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

2020-10-15 17:32:19.285819+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537699] [YandexMobileMetrica] Client event is saved to db: Игрок НЕ прошёл 4 уровень, он врезался в препятствие. (apiKey: 8eee54b7-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx96bf).
2020-10-15 17:32:20.222041+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537558] [YandexMobileMetrica] Client event is sent: Игрок НЕ прошёл 4 уровень, он врезался в препятствие. (apiKey: 8eee54b7-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx96bf).
2020-10-15 17:32:20.222195+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537558] [YandexMobileMetrica] Client event is sent: Игрок решил посмотреть (продолжить уровень) рекламу. (apiKey: 8eee54b7-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx96bf).
2020-10-15 17:32:20.222613+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537558] [YandexMobileMetrica] Client event is sent: Игрок посмотрел (продолжить уровень) рекламу. (apiKey: 8eee54b7-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx96bf).
2020-10-15 17:32:20.222721+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537558] [YandexMobileMetrica] Client event is sent: Игрок НЕ прошёл 4 уровень, он врезался в препятствие. (apiKey: 8eee54b7-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx96bf).
2020-10-15 17:32:20.233074+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537558] [YandexMobileMetrica] Client event is removed from db: Игрок НЕ прошёл 4 уровень, он врезался в препятствие. (apiKey: 8eee54b7-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx96bf).
2020-10-15 17:32:20.233203+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537558] [YandexMobileMetrica] Client event is removed from db: Игрок решил посмотреть (продолжить уровень) рекламу. (apiKey: 8eee54b7-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx96bf).
2020-10-15 17:32:20.233337+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537558] [YandexMobileMetrica] Client event is removed from db: Игрок посмотрел (продолжить уровень) рекламу. (apiKey: 8eee54b7-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx96bf).
2020-10-15 17:32:20.236549+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537558] [YandexMobileMetrica] Client event is removed from db: Игрок НЕ прошёл 4 уровень, он врезался в препятствие. (apiKey: 8eee54b7-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx96bf).
haptics stoped (usually because they have finished playing)
System.Action:Invoke()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Unloading 5 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
UnloadTime: 8.909333 ms
Level loaded 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)


Unloading 6 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 38455.
Total: 15.427625 ms (FindLiveObjects: 1.797917 ms CreateObjectMapping: 2.438500 ms MarkObjects: 11.082000 ms  DeleteObjects: 0.108458 ms)

0 + -28 + 60 + 150 + 22.5 = 204.5 - finishZPos
LevelSpawner:SpawnLevel()
LevelSpawner:Start()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

2020-10-15 17:32:27.484782+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537558] [YandexMobileMetrica] Client event is received: Игрок НЕ прошёл 4 уровень, он врезался в препятствие. (apiKey: 8eee54b7-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx96bf).
Market saved
System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
Player:Crash(ObstacleChunkGroup)
Obstacle:Crashed(Player)
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

2020-10-15 17:32:27.497750+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537558] [YandexMobileMetrica] Client event is saved to db: Игрок НЕ прошёл 4 уровень, он врезался в препятствие. (apiKey: 8eee54b7-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx96bf).
-> applicationWillResignActive()
2020-10-15 17:32:29.916826+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
haptics stoped (usually because they have finished playing)
System.Action:Invoke()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

2020-10-15 17:32:30.875377+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
-> applicationDidEnterBackground()
2020-10-15 17:32:31.087629+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 12 (0xc), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.
2020-10-15 17:32:31.088078+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:31.088200+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:31.088301+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:31.088486+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:31.089640+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
--//--
2020-10-15 17:32:34.145587+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:34.145954+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:34.162213+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2020-10-15 17:32:34.162457+0300 veganrunner[4766:1537272] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
```

I will be glad for any help and ready to answer any questions

Comment: Great, detailed question. Some small questions: What is a "complete unit game"? Also, what were you using to implement this? (The tags suggest Unity3d.) What happens when you run the game without the ad?

Comment: I meant a full game, which means with sounds, with vibration (I use nice vibration asset), with ads (admob), with analytics (yandex metrika), in-game purchases and etc. To create a game, I use unity version 2019.4.12f1, and to build the application xcode version 11.6. When I build a project without ads or if an advertisement is played without sound, then there is no problem

Comment: pure guess ... assure you properly close and release assets like the audio device when exiting admob

Comment: thx for help all of u. i found a solution

Comment: @ArtsemGorbatchev
Any chances to share your solution? I have the same issue on my side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple introduced a pressure-sensitive technology in 2015 called 3D Touch. But in 2018 the tech fell out of favour, and the iPhone XR, iPhone SE and iPhone 11 models replaced it with Haptic Touch, if I'm not mistaken.

My problem was related to the asst which I imported to implement vibration (Nice vibrations). this asset offers advanced vibration that only works on newer phones. In general, the error was caused by the reproduction of this vibration, I decided not to bother and simply refused to use this type of vibration. I wrote to the developer to fix the bug.

I would be glad if someone provides a solution that will presuppose the preservation of this type of vibration, but I think this is a specific question and i won't waste time on this.